# 32 bit ODBC driver on a 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64 bit windows server 2008 R2 system. I want to install the Btrieve ODBC driver on this system, but there is only a 32 bit version of Btrieve ODBC available.

Is there any way to install this 32 bit driver in my 64 bit server system ?

---

I installed a installation monitoring tool in another 2003 32 bit server and installed the btrieve 32 bit odbc driver in the same system using the monitoring tool. Then I got the files  and reg entries changed during the installation of btrieve odbc 32 bit  in 32 bit system. According to this I copied corresponding files and changed reg entries in my 64 bit os. And I found that the pervasive driver is listed. But the thing is that when we try to add this pervasive driver in to dsn getting an error:

> "The setup routine for the pervasive software odbc 32 ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 126: The specified module couldnot be found(C:\WINDOWS\System 32\w32btstp.dll) "

Answer (score 5):

A 64-bit Windows will allow you to create DSNs usable by 32-bit applications and DSNs usable by 64-bit applications. Run the files listed below to create them:

```
64-bit:
C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe
32-bit:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

Comment: i have tried this already. but in the driver list pervasive odbc was not listed.